# Nested foreach() loop php Codeigniter-Php error

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I'm getting `Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

on this line `foreach($element->action as $URI){ // find action="" attr of <form> element`

My code is a nested foreach() loop:

```
           $siteToSearch = file_get_html($prefix.$sss);
                foreach($siteToSearch->find('form') as $element){ // find <form> element
                    foreach($element->action as $URI){ // find action="" attr of <form> element
                        $submit_vars["name"] = "' OR ''='";                     
                        $submit_vars["passwd"] = "' OR ''='";                   
                        $submit_vars["submit"] = "Submit";  
                        $snoopy->submit($URI,$submit_vars);
                        echo "response code: ".$snoopy->response_code."<br>\n";
                        print $snoopy->results;
                    }
   }
```

I tried defining `$URI` on the first line as `$URI = $element->action;` but this doesnt seem to fix it

Comment: Why is this nested loops? The outer loop seems to be looping through all the `<form>` elements, but the inner loop only makes sense if you're assuming each `<form>` might have multiple actions.

Comment: Great point john. Could you post this as an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" message when the argument (here it's, `$element->action`) isn't an array (or something array-like).

I think the problem here is that you really don't need the inner `foreach` loop at all. `$element->action` seems to be representing the "action" attribute of an HTML form element. Each form will only have one action, which will probably be represented in PHP as a string, not an array.

Taking out the inner loop and simply adding a line like you mentioned, `$URI = $element->action`, should fix this problem.

Comment: Great idea, got confused in my own logic here.Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

please check that `$element->action` have some value or not please use `print_r( $element);` after the first loop and please put the inner loop in the contion ==>`if($element->action) { }`

the code will be something like given below

`$siteToSearch = file_get_html($prefix.$sss);
                foreach($siteToSearch->find('form') as $element){ // find <form> element
                  if($element->action)
                  {
                    foreach($element->action as $URI){ // find action="" attr of <form> element
                        $submit_vars["name"] = "' OR ''='";

                        $submit_vars["passwd"] = "' OR ''='";

                        $submit_vars["submit"] = "Submit";

                        $snoopy->submit($URI,$submit_vars);
                        echo "response code: ".$snoopy->response_code."<br>\n";
                        print $snoopy->results;
                    }
                   } 
  }`